# Common way to let a user pick data in a huge searchable list

Tags: javascript, html, list, user-interface

I want to let my users select certain data from a list on my webpage.

I did this by now like this:

[image: Screenshot]

But it looks messy and confusing I think (and was told so by my supervisor).

I want the entries to be searchable, but it doesn't has to be as sophisticated as it is now (search every single column) and they don't need to be sortable.

I also don't need separate lists for the selected and available items.

Given these conditions is there a common / good way to let a user pick data in a searchable list with a lot of entries?

Edit: It seems my question was imprecise here a rephrased version:

**Are there ways to present the data to the user which are easier to understand. So I am asking for common UI-Patterns for this usecase.**

Comment: Search first then show the results. that way the user only sees the results they want not all the one's they don't. But it very much depends on what data you viewing and who is viewing it and why?!

Comment: list.js and jquery datatables plugin offer such features with little work on your end...

Comment: if you use jQuery you can use .find()

Comment: Oh no, maybe my question was not precise enough, i asked for ways to presentate the data to the user which are easier to understand. So i was asking for common UI-Patterns for this usecase. I edited my question now.

Comment: I still don't get what you want. Do you want to display the searchfields in a nicer way or the resulting data-table?

Comment: Another way to present data that _could_ be presented in a table to the user to let him choose from entries. There don't have to be columns or a table at all. For example a single search field would be one simplification... I was asking if there is a well known solution to that.

Comment: I still don't get it :D I present my solution to my problem: I had a table with 200 entries and wanted this table to have a filter on every field. I made a popup (jQueryUI Dialog) with tabs to sort the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are quite a few designs to get ideas from here: http://ui-patterns.com/explore/collections/lists

I would suggest having only 1 search box which searches all fields, then you could even hide the less important ones until you have searched - `display:none;` - so that the data is still there and searchable but not immediately visible.

The best would be to work out what is essential to be shown and what is not essential and work from there.

Comment: I think i will go for your idea with only one searchbox and introduce a simple "search language" like "field2: blub field1:bla" or simple "something" to search in all fields for the keyword and also i will remove the second list and just let the user click the plus which denn "selects" the data immediatly and removes it from the list.

Comment: @NickRussler I wouldn't introduce a "search language"...remember the old paradigm (which I may of just made up) *"if you have to train the users, you've got it wrong, it should be obvious"*